# React theme working on localhost not in AWS Machine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services

I am on ReactJS v15.3.1, using node v8.3.1 and npm v5.0.4
I am trying to implement a react app using this theme [SB Admin React](https://startreact.com/themes/sb-admin-react-3/)
it's working fine when I run this into the localhost all pages loads fine and everything working as expected, but when I move this theme to my AWS machine with the same configurations(node and npm) as my localhost it starts throwing this error on browser console:

> GET http://34.192.38.113:3001/assets/main.js?6f764c822b1f287a2e02 net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Maybe because of this whenever I click on any link on my theme page on browser it refresh the page and shows the same error

I tried using different themes as well but the same error (highlighted in code block) persist with all of them. 
I am unable to get the root cause for this,
Also, I've made all the ports available in my AWS machine.

How to rectify this issue?

Comment: I am also getting a similar issue, but with a different theme. GET http://45.58.47.49:3000/assets/app.js net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH